# Проект на Django не загружается с Ubuntu VPS, после настроек gunicorn, supervisor и nginx

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, supervisor

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой, произвел все настройки на сервере, проверил работу gunicorn, запустил проект напрямую командой `gunicorn Superman.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8001`, сайт запустился, но без static файлов. Далее установил supervisor, так же произвел отдельную настройку под него и настроил nginx, при проверке supervisor `sudo supervisorctl status Superman` сервер ответил, что он работает, при проверке nginx `sudo nginx -t` сервер так же отвечает положительно successful, но когда я забиваю IP своего сайта в строку поиска браузера сайт не прогружается, ошибка - Сайт 91.228.152.32 не позволяет установить соединение, в логах nginx пусто. В чем может быть проблема, возможно я неправильно настраиваю proxy_pass? Настройки прилагаю ниже, ПРОШУ ПОМОЧЬ В РЕШЕНИИ ПРОБЛЕМЫ, сутки ищу решение и ничего((

Настройка Gunicorn

```
NAME="Superman-test"                                  
DJANGODIR=/webapps/Superman-test/Superman             
SOCKFILE=/webapps/Superman-test/run/gunicorn.sock 
GROUP=www-data                                      
NUM_WORKERS=3                                     
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=Superman.settings             
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=Superman.wsgi                     

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH


RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \     
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```

Настройка Supervisor

```
[program:Superman]
command = sh /webapps/Superman-test/bin/gunicorn_start 
user = root 
stdout_logfile = /webapps/Superman-test/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log 
redirect_stderr = true 
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Настройка Nginx

```
upstream Superman-test_server {
  server unix:/webapps/Superman-test/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen   80;
    server_name 91.228.152.32;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /webapps/Superman-test/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/Superman-test/logs/nginx-error.log;
 
    location /static/ {
        alias /webapps/Superman-test/Superman/static/;
    }
    
    location /media/ {
        alias /webapps/Superman-test/Superman/static/app/image/;
    }

    location / {
        if(!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://Superman-test_server;
            break;
        }
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = / 500.html {
        root /webapps/Superman-test/static/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nginx -t` -- протестировать конфиг nginx. это не про "запущен".

`ps -ef` -- посмотреть, какие процессы запущены.

`sudo lsof -Pi | grep LISTEN` -- посмотреть, какие процессы на каком **ip** и порту слушают.

---

Так на любой запрос сначала смотрится, есть ли файл в /app/static, если нет -- идет на бакенд:

```
    server {
        ...
        root     /app/static; #static files
        location / {
            try_files  $uri @backend;
        }
        location @backend {
            proxy_pass     http://127.0.0.1:1979;
            ...
        }
    }
```

Отдельные location не описываются.

Comment: После проверки открытых портов, мне нужно указать в настройках Nginx этот порт? Проверил так же через `ps -ef` Nginx и Gunicorn запущены.

Comment: lsof говорит какие адрес:порт **уже** используются, и кем. у вас nginx по мнению lsof на каком порту и адресе?

Comment: nginx не фигурирует при проверке через lsof, только sshd и postgres. в чем проблема может быть?

Comment: При проверке через `ps -ef` процессы Nginx и Gunicorn запущены, `nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/ng` и `gunicorn: master [Superman]`

Comment: а lsof с sudo был? ... может это nginx со старыми настройками, или настройками с другого места, тогда убить его, и запустить правильный ... можно `curl -v 127.0.0.1` посмотреть на всякий ... можно закомментить всё в конфиге nginx про супермана, и посмотреть, будет ли отвечать просто nginx ... у nginx я вижу не только master, но и worker process

Comment: Спасибо за советы, помогла переустановка nginx, но с настройками все равно возникли трудности, через `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` не считываются настройки и файла default там нет, удалось сделать запуск проекта через `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`, но статика не подгружается почему то и выдает ошибку если добавляешь больше одного location с адресами до статических файлов, но даже если оставляешь один путь и он корректный, то все равно не запускается, в журнале событий ` nginx: [emerg] "alias" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:10`, недоволен что путь не один...

Comment: добавил вариант;  вы б конфиг перепредставили в вопросе

Comment: Все решилась проблема, я не верно понял суть location, заработало когда указал `location /static/css/ {root /webapps/Superman-test/Superman/; }`, вместо `location /static/ {root /webapps/Superman-test/Superman/static/css/; }`. Спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: Всегда рад....)